# funcion calcule interes simple

Tags: python

Necesito crear una función que me arroje esto: Para el usuario AB1012 La cantidad de dinero a recibir, según el monto inicial 1000000 para un tiempo de 3 meses es: 1007500.0 y necesito que se ejecute a través de esto: print(CDT("AB1012",1000000,3))

**Mi código**

```py
def CDT(usuario: str,capital: int, tiempo:int):
    a=print("Para el usuario AB1012 La cantidad de dinero a recibir, según el monto inicial 1000000 para un tiempo de 3 meses es:1007500.0")
    print(a)
```

la función debe ser llamada de esta forma `print(CDT("AB1012",1000000,3))`, Lo siento no conozco muy bien el lenguaje.

Comment: KHE !? .. ok fuera del meme... lee [ask] para entender como preguntar... pero te lo resumo.... Explica tu problema, muestra que tienes, y que quieres lograr... y que se pueda entender obvio.

Comment: es que no se como manejar esta cosa y me dice muchos errores... necesito crear una funcion que me arroje esto:  Para el usuario AB1012 La cantidad de dinero a recibir, según el monto inicial 1000000 para un tiempo de 3 meses es: 1007500.0           y  necesito que se ejecute a traves de esto: print(CDT("AB1012",1000000,3))     es en Python

Comment: cual es el calculo u operacion que tienes que hacer para obtener `1007500.0`, dime eso y mejorare tu pregunta

Comment: son dos operaciones, la primera es 1000000*3*0.03/12, la segunda operacion es 100000+7500.0, que se obtiene de 1000000*0.02

Comment: Def CDT(usuario: str, capital: int, tiempo: int):
 ''' CDT
 : Parámetros: usuario (str): alfanumérico
que identifica el usurario capital (int):
Monto a ingresar tiempo (int): Tiempo del
CDT
:
 String: de la forma “Las ganancias obtenidas para un monto de {}, en un tiempo de {} es:
{}" para el caso de ganancias, para las "La cantidad de dinero a recibir, según el monto inicial
{}, para un tiempo de {} es: {}" dice que el esqueleto de la solucion debe contener esto

Comment: ok esto es un problema de interes simple, no?

Comment: 3 es el tiempo, 0.03/12 es el interes 3% anual, no? y 100000 es el capital

Comment: asi es, hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo entonces pues aja

Comment: y lo que pasa es que una plataforma es la que lo verifica y segun entiendo ejecuta la funcion con este codigo: print(CDT("AB1012",1000000,3))

Comment: hare una respuesta cuando la pregunta sea editada, no tengo el poder de editar inmediatamente la pregunta,envie la edicion falta ser aprobada o rechazada

Comment: @Alejandro ahora podes agregar una respuesta.

Comment: @Christian por favor lee el [tour].. usa el boton [edit] para editar tu publicacion...

Comment: @gbianchi ya me lo lei, la cosa que antes no podia publicar una respuesta por lo que acepte el otro metodo(gmail)

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que hay que hacer es estructurar bien la función y aplicar las formulas, correspondientes

**Función**

```py
def CDT(usuario: str,capital: int, tiempo:int, interes:int):
     #este condicional es para poder sacar el interes de 2 formas
     # si el usuario ingresa el interes en forma 0.03
     # o si se pone de la forma 3 % (sin el %)
     if type(interes) is not float:
          interes = (interes/100)/12
     else:
       interes = (interes/12)
     monto = capital * (interes) * tiempo #formula del interes simple
     montoFinal = monto+capital 
     mensaje = f'Para el usuario {usuario} La cantidad de dinero a recibir, según el monto inicial {capital} para un tiempo de {tiempo} meses es:{montoFinal}' #se emplea los F-Strings
     return mensaje
```

**Uso**

```
print(CDT("AB1012",1000000,3,0.03))
#Para el usuario AB1012 La cantidad de dinero a recibir, según el monto inicial 1000000 para un tiempo de 3 meses es:1007500.0

#tambien se le puede pasar el interes como el `3`%
print(CDT("AB1012",1000000,3,3))
#Para el usuario AB1012 La cantidad de dinero a recibir, según el monto inicial 1000000 para un tiempo de 3 meses es:1007500.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberás crear la función llamada CDT. Esto en Python se hace con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
def CDT(usuario: str, capital: int, tiempo: int):
    # contenido
    return valor
```

Los parámetros los tienes bien. Son los datos que utilizará la función para hacer el cálculo interno y luego retornar un valor.

Fuera del código, debes despejar la variable `tasa` de la fórmula del interés simple (a papel y lápiz si gustas).

Luego, utilizando operadores `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, puedes calcular una variable `tasa = ...` utilizando los parámetros de tu función.

Finalmente, deberás retornar el mensaje con el valor que calculaste. Eso lo puedes hacer así:

```
mensaje = "Para el usuario {}, la cantidad de dinero a recibir, según el monto inicial {} para un tiempo de {} meses es: {}".format(usuario, capital, tiempo, tasa)
return mensaje
```

Ten en cuenta el orden de las variables.

Así, puedes llamar a tu función utilizando:

```
print(CDT('AB1012', 1000000, 3))
```

Comment: Hola Gustavo, tengo otra duda lo que pasa es que en el problema me dice que cuando el tiempo es inferior o igual a dos meses el capital debe multiplicarse por 0.02, como podria programar el codigo de Christian para que cuando coloque el 2 o 1 multiplique el capital por 0.02 en vez de 0.03... gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Alejandro para ello, dentro de la función deberás utilizar un condicional `if/else` verificando si el tiempo es menor o igual a dos meses, utilizando un comparador `<=`.  En cada caso, modificas la tasa según corresponda. Acá hay una guía para que aprendas la sintaxis: https://pythones.net/if-else-elif-condicionales/ Recuerda marcar la respuesta que más te haya ayudado como aceptada.